# Using combobox in databound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, databound

Looking for a sample of a databound datagridview in vb.net.  Each row needs a cell with a combobox that receives its data from an access database.  The user should be able to make choices from the combobox and change the data.  The data is specific and the multiple choices are always the same.  This should be a simple, common situation, but not finding any samples.  I know how to bind a datagridview with a database using text-style cells, but inserting a combobox appears to be way complicated.

Comment: take a look http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.ca/2008/09/binding-datagridview-combobox-column.html

Comment: Thank You Thank You Thank You Walter.  This has just saved me hundreds of hours of agonizing.  Almost exactly what I needed.